# Breadcrumbs stopped going to third level

Tags: breadcrumbs

I'm still learning Drupal, so have a basic understanding, and have been assigned to fix our breadcrumbs.  Apparently it used to go to the 3rd level on this page ([https://ccom.unh.edu/theme/auvs](http://ccom.unh.edu/theme/auvs)), but it no longer does, only to the 2nd level.  It should say Home>Research>AUVs, but it only says Home>Research.

The Crumbs module wasn't installed.  I've been looking through our modules to try to figure out what is doing the breadcrumbs, but I don't see anything.  If I install the Crumbs module I can't even find instructions on how to implement it.  Can someone give me some guidance here please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can search for `theme_breadcrumb()`, they may develop it with this function ( search in template.php )

Comment: The only thing there was a breadcrumb function to use a customized arrow as the separator.

Answer (score 0):

Your breadcrumb is likely dependant on the actual menu structure. As such it is quite possible that the menu structure itself has changed, especially if untrained editors don't respect certain conventions when making changes.
Thanks to [archive.org](http://archive.org/web/) we can take a look at past versions of your site:

- [Feb 25, 2013](http://web.archive.org/web/20130225014946/http://ccom.unh.edu/theme/auvs)
- [Feb 12, 2014](http://web.archive.org/web/20140212185948/http://ccom.unh.edu/theme/auvs)
- [April 6, 2015](http://web.archive.org/web/20150406134245/http://ccom.unh.edu/theme/auvs)

You will notice that the breadcrumb only changes between 2014 and 2015, now displaying the "Research" item twice.

To narrow down the origin of the problem there are a few approaches:

1. Inspect the menu structure to see if there even exists a third level (assuming the breadcrumb is actually derived from it).
2. Inspect the remaining archive.org snapshots that lie in between the ones listed above for 2014 and 2015, until you find the closest two that differ.
3. If the code is [versioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control), inspect commits that fall into that time range.
4. If there are database backups, set up a local installation that uses an older version of the DB contents.